# How to get phone number of user from Facebook in my android app by integrating Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have integrated **Facebook SDK** with my android app , I login Successfully in **Facebook** and i easily get user **name, email,gender** but i need one more extra Information that is **user phone number** .

I searched lots of link and Facebook documentation to get **mobile number** from Facebook but not any link provide me details to how to get phone no . I also got some link that say that now Facebook is not providing user phone no , but i found some application on **play store** that is **UBER and  NAUKARI.com** get **phone number** from **Facebook** .

If some link say that Facebook disabled that feature then how some application from **play store** get **user mobile number** from Facebook. If Facebook allow that application to get **phone number** then there is defiantly any Mechanism to get user phone number , So I need **phone number** from Facebook . So please provide me details about how to get User **phone number** from **Facebook** .

Comment: there is still no way to get the phone number with the facebook api, there probably never will be a way. play store apps do not access the phone number with the facebook api, but with the phone permissions. there is no relation to the facebook api at all.

Comment: @luschn  then how  UBER   app get phone number from Facebook

Comment: please read my comment again...they do not get it from facebook. getting the phone number in a mobile hap has nothing to do with facebook.

Comment: @luschn  I agree with u but when i changed  mobile number in Facebook account  then in UBER app i get updated mobile number which is i updated in my Facebook account . and i using UBER app in mobile which not contain any simcard. Than how they get my updated mobile number  of Facebook

Comment: you would have to ask uber then, but we can only tell you that there is no way to get the mobile number with the facebook api. there are a lot of threads about it, and the api reference does not list it either.